# Calling a php function in itself using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, socialengine

I'm currently developing a widget in social engine.
what I am trying to do now is to call a php function within the loaded page using jQuery(the jQuery file is an external file) but all I can find is by to use .get , .post or .ajax in. are there any ways to call the function? 
Since it is built in socialengine, I am only allowed to load Controller.php and index.tpl for php files. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot call a php function from jQuery like that. You must use the ajax, get, or post methods of jQuery.

Comment: php is server side js client side so you have to make a call to the server using .get , .post or .ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call php function from JavaScript, but you could call the current page and pass parameters in the request.  It would require a reload of the page, but your PHP app could check for parameters and execute function.

```
<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 0:
        someFunction();
        break;
    case 1:
        anotherFunction();
        break;
    default:
        // do nothing
        break;
}

function someFunction() {

}

function anotherFunction() {

}
?>
```

... do something and call jQuery GET to page passing ?action=0 for example in request.

There is a possibility you could build something using ajax with JSONP with a callback, so your PHP app executes callback but probably more complex that what you need.